# calculate the time spent by employee in R using his hire date and termination date

Tags: r

I have a dataframe:

```
df = data.frame('Id' = c(101, 103, 104, 101, 105, 101, 103, 106, 104),
                'action' = c('HIRE', 'Terminate', 'HIRE', 'Terminate', 'Hire', 'Promoted', 'Hire', 'Hire', 'Terminate'),
                'date'= c('02/01/2017', '01/23/2019', '05/13/2017', '04/1/2019', '05/22/2017', '08/12/2018', '09/30/2017', '02/11/2017', '12/12/2019'))
```

I want to create a new column, using the difference between hire and termination date if it is available in the data to know how much time a person spent before leaving. I'm new to R so any help would be appreciated.

I thought of grouping the data but i'm not sure how we can perform using this data

Comment: In your real data do you both the values 'HIRE' as well as 'hire', 'Terminate' as well as 'TERMINATE' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date, '%m/%d/%Y')) %>%
  group_by(Id) %>%
  summarise(time_spent_in_days = as.numeric(difftime(date[action == 'Terminate'],
                                  date[action == 'Hire'], units = 'days')))

#     Id time_spent_in_days
#  <dbl>              <dbl>
#1   101                789
#2   103                480
#3   104                943
```

Assuming all the `action` values has the same text for same action. In your data you have `'HIRE'` as well as `'hire'`.

Comment: Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `time_spent`.
x character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
i Input `time_spent` is `difftime(EFFDT[ACTION == "TER"], EFFDT[ACTION == "HIR"], units = "days")`.
i The error occurred in group 1: ID = 101.

Comment: I'm getting this error, i tried using as.numericon EFFDT[ACTION=='TER] and EFFDT[ACTION=='HIR'], but I get the blank row

Comment: Are you trying this on the data that you have shared or some different data?

Comment: This works for me without any issue/error on the data that you have shared. Maybe you have `plyr` loaded. Try to use `dplyr::mutate` or `dplyr::summarise`

Comment: df$EFFDT=mdy(df$EFFDT)

df %>%
    mutate(date = as.Date(EFFDT)) %>%
    group_by(EMPLID) %>%
    summarise(time_spent = as.numeric(difftime(EFFDT[ACTION == 'TER'], EFFDT[ACTION == 'HIR'], units = 'days')))

Comment: i'm getting the grouped data with date calculated but how can we add others column too of original data with this grouped data

Comment: Which columns do you want to add? With what values? You can add those values in `summarise` with `col1 = first(col1), col2 = first(col2)` to get first values.

Comment: above code gives me a two values, Id and time_spent, I want to get Action column also in the result with its original value

Comment: There are multiple values in action column which one do you want? If you want to keep the same number of rows as your original data and add a new column you can use `mutate` instead of `summarise`.

Comment: yeah i want to use same no. of rows as original data

Comment: Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `time_spent`-- I get this error whhen I use mutate

Comment: What is the complete error message that you get?

Comment: Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `time_spent`.
x Input `time_spent` can't be recycled to size 2.
i Input `time_spent` is `as.numeric(...)`.
i Input `time_spent` must be size 2 or 1, not 0.
i The error occurred in group 2: EMPLID = 22000002

Comment: I have used inner join and it got me the result

Comment: df2=df %>%
    mutate(date = as.Date(EFFDT)) %>%
    group_by(EMPLID) %>%
    summarise(time_spent = as.numeric(difftime(EFFDT[ACTION == 'TER'], EFFDT[ACTION == 'HIR'], units = 'days')))%>%
    inner_join(df,by='EMPLID')

Comment: how can we do the same thing if we have more than two categories, like hire, terminate and partner, want to calculate the time between hire and partner also in the same code, so that time spent.

Comment: Can you add that as a new question with an appropriate example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65251895/calculate-difference-between-dates-for-different-actions-in-r     -- added