# calculate difference between dates for different actions in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this:

```
d=data.frame('Id'=c(101,101,101,101,103,103,103),
             'Action'=c('hire','terminate','promoted','promoted','hire','promoted','terminate'),
             'date'=c('02/22/2017','12/11/2020','11/11/2018','03/22/2019','02/23/2016','01/12/2018','03/21/2019'))
```

I want to create a new column `time_spent` which calculates the day between hire date and terminate date, and the hire date and promoted date.

```
df$date=mdy(df$date)

df %>%
    mutate(date = as.Date(EFFDT)) %>%
    group_by(EMPLID) %>%
    summarise(time_spent = as.numeric(difftime(EFFDT[ACTION == 'TER'], EFFDT[ACTION == 'HIR'], units = 'days')))%>%
    inner_join(df,by='EMPLID')
```

Above code calculates the time but it's between hire and terminate. How can we do for hire and promoted?

Also if we see that for `Id` 101 promotion happens twice we have two different dates. So if we apply the above code for hire and promoted it only calculates the days between hire and the first occurrence of promoted Action for `Id` 101, and not all promoted Action which happened for `Id` 101.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this might be helpful. Instead of `summarise` and `inner_join` you can use `mutate` and have the new column `time_spent` be the time difference between that row's `date` and `date` when the person was hired.

```
library(tidyverse)

d %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")) %>%
  arrange(Id, date) %>%
  group_by(Id) %>%
  mutate(time_spent = difftime(date, date[Action == "hire"], units = "days"))
```

**Output**

```
     Id Action    date       time_spent
  <dbl> <chr>     <date>     <drtn>    
1   101 hire      2017-02-22    0 days 
2   101 promoted  2018-11-11  627 days 
3   101 promoted  2019-03-22  758 days 
4   101 terminate 2020-12-11 1388 days 
5   103 hire      2016-02-23    0 days 
6   103 promoted  2018-01-12  689 days 
7   103 terminate 2019-03-21 1122 days
```

**Edit**: If you want to include `NA` when no "hire" date is available, you can `filter` to include `Id` that has `any` "hire" and then rejoin data again. Just make sure data frame has `date` in correct format first.

```
d$date <- as.Date(d$date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")

d %>%
  arrange(Id, date) %>%
  group_by(Id) %>%
  filter(any(Action == "hire")) %>%
  mutate(time_spent = difftime(date, date[Action == "hire"], units = "days")) %>%
  right_join(d)
```

**Data**

```
d <- structure(list(Id = c(101, 101, 101, 101, 103, 103, 103), Action = c("hire", 
"terminate", "promoted", "promoted", "hire", "promoted", "terminate"
), date = c("02/22/2017", "12/11/2020", "11/11/2018", "03/22/2019", 
"02/23/2016", "01/12/2018", "03/21/2019")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: Thanks Ben, I have one doubt let say we  have one more ID- 104, and we dont have action 'hire' but we have other actions- terminate, promoted, then this is going to throw an error: 'error occurred in group : Id = 104, how can we handle this situation'

Comment: @Nishant See edited answer. You can add a `filter` to only include `Id` that has "hire" somewhere in a row. Then, rejoin the data. Just make sure `date` is in correct format first. Hope this helps!